# javax.management.MalformedObjectException. Invalid character ':' in value part of property

Tags: java, tomcat, ant, zk

War file for my web application built using **ant** is working fine on **Tomcat** (version 8.0.18) on **Windows** machine. However if I deploy the same war on Tomcat (same version) installed on **Linux** machine, it throws the error:
*javax.management.MalformedObjectException. Invalid character ':' in value part of property*. I did the primary checks like cleaning Tomcat work folder, checking for duplicate jars etc. But no luck.

Comment: Also at the same time in server log, I have observed the "org.apache.catalina.LifeCycleException: Failed to start component." exception. This is because my war is not uploaded due to previous error.

Comment: Surprising thing is that when I deploy the war file on linux by putting it directly in Tomcat's webapp folder; the build is successful. Application runs fine. Problem is with Tomcat 'manager/html' war upload approach only.

Comment: Today I checked by deploying using Jenkins (ant buidl) on linux machine, and there are no problems at all.

Answer (score 1):

Sound like you have a hard coded windows path somewhere in your code like "c:\" - because there is no colon ':' in linux paths allowed.

Try to use relative paths only in your code.

Comment: Checked but the hardcoded path like "C:\" is commented in property file. Also did one round of testing by removing that path completely from property file. But the same error.

Comment: Ok, is there another property value that contains a colon?

Comment: Hmm also could be a characterset problem of the properties file.